# Take user input to complete missing values

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need some sort of guidance on what would be the best way of accomplishing such kind of task in SAS EG environment (on a 9.4 server). Let's say I have table named ITEM_EVALUATION like in the following example. The missing evaluations (rows: 4,5 and 6) should be filled in by the user. Although there may be better solutions, I would prefer if SAS iterated over the missing rows, give the user the row information (item) and take the input (evaluation) then update the table by that input.

Since this task is going to be a part of another sas eg project (egp), I need to do it within this project, so please advise...

*ITEM_EVALUATION.sas7bdat*

| ROW | ITEM | EVALUATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | owned |
| 2 | house | rent |
| 3 | cat | none |
| 4 | phone |  |
| 5 | job |  |
| 6 | vacation |  |
| 7 |  |  |

Comment: That's really application type functionality, where the optimal solution is not SAS. You can get it to work but it's cumbersome and requires some other tools most likely - JavaScript or C++.

Comment: This may be a good starting point https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/330-2009.pdf

Comment: Thank you, cascading prompts and dependency concepts seem promising, I will be experimenting with it. Too bad we cannot simply invoke prompts inside a loop or change their parameters during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dataset occurs in your project. (Drag it to a flow, for instance.)

Ask your user to double click any empty cell in the table and accept to go to edit mode.

If the empty cells are rare, the user can enter a filter `missing(ITEM) or missing(EVALUATION)` on top of the data to find them.

If that is too complex for your user, Enterprise Guide is not the tool for this person.